# Wt: fatal error: call to empty boost::function

Tags: c++, boost, wt

I am trying to build the "Wt" library (in version 3.3.5) on my own, but failing when I try to run the Example.

My environment is a Debian with Boost 1.53.0 for which I want to build the library.

Compiling and linking (gcc 4.7.2) works well, but when I try to run the Wt-Example (http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/wt.html), the Server fails with:

**Wt: fatal error: call to empty boost::function**

Complete Log is:

```
foo@rtm:/tmp/$ wt_test --docroot .  --http-address 0.0.0.0 --http-port 9090
Option no-compression is implied because wthttp was built without zlib support.
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:29.326974] 6436 - [info] "config: reading Wt config file: /etc/wt/wt_config.xml (location = 'wt_test')"
Option no-compression is implied because wthttp was built without zlib support.
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:29.327938] 6436 - [info] "WServer/wthttp: initializing built-in wthttpd"
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:29.328281] 6436 - [info] "wthttp: started server: http://0.0.0.0:9090"
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:33.971973] 6436 - [info] "Wt: session created (#sessions = 1)"
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:33.972423] 6436 [/ mZ4BIN0ZPoVnqQTG] [info]     "WEnvironment: UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0)     Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0"
10.12.5.50 - - [2016-Feb-11 10:35:33.974561] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4691
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:33.974722] 6436 - [info] "WebRequest: took 3.044ms"
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:34.026134] 6436 [/ mZ4BIN0ZPoVnqQTG] [error] "Wt: fatal error: call to empty boost::function"
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:34.026242] 6436 - [info] "WebController: Removing session mZ4BIN0ZPoVnqQTG"
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:34.026293] 6436 [/ mZ4BIN0ZPoVnqQTG] [info] "Wt: session destroyed (#sessions = 0)"
10.12.5.50 - - [2016-Feb-11 10:35:34.026374] "GET /?wtd=mZ4BIN0ZPoVnqQTG&sid=2063522618&webGL=true&scrW=1680&scrH=1050&tz=60&htmlHistory=true&deployPath=%2F&request=script&rand=4063601615 HTTP/1.1" 500 84
10.12.5.50 - - [2016-Feb-11 10:35:34.026375] "GET /?wtd=mZ4BIN0ZPoVnqQTG&request=style&page=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:34.026414] 6436 - [info] "WebRequest: took 0.5ms"
[2016-Feb-11 10:35:34.026430] 6436 - [info] "WebRequest: took 30.593ms"
```

Does anybody have an idea how to find out what is going wrong here?

I know the Boost Version isn't up-to-date, but I guess this shouldn't be a problem?

Regads, 
VanDahlen

Answer (score 0):

I get this warning:

> `boost_1_60_0/boost/signal.hpp|17 col 4| warning: #warning "Boost.Signals is no longer being maintained and is now deprecated. Please switch to Boost.Signals2. To disable this warning message, define BOOST_SIGNALS_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING." [-Wcpp]`

This look like it could have a lot to do with things.

That said, it just works and runs cleanly under valgrind on my Ubuntu box using g++-5. (It does fail to link when using libc++)

Comment: No, it doesn't have an effect when using Boost 1.60.0 and Signals2. The Error is still the same. Pretty strange..

Comment: Huh. How did you test this with signals 2?

Comment: I've set up Boost 1.60.0 and ran cmake; Wconfig.h contains `#define WT_USE_BOOST_SIGNALS2`.